# Is there a keyboard / mouse shortcut for paste in MobaXTerm?

Tags: putty, mobaxterm

The right click is the shortcut for putty to perform a paste in the terminal.

Is there a similar shortcut in MobaXTerm?

Comment: To paste where? In the terminal?

Comment: Yes. And that is what right click does in putty.

Answer (score 22):

Found a keyboard shortcut in Settings/Keyboard Shortcuts. The default keyboard shortcut is Shift-Insert which can be mapped to something else.

Comment: [shift+insert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key) is even older than ctrl+C and still works as the [paste shortcut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste#Common_keyboard_shortcuts) in both Windows and Linux

Comment: Ctrl+Insert is also works as the copy shortcut for selected text

Comment: please notice "settings" is the top toolbar "settings", not the icon. They are different things.

Answer (score 7):

You can have the right click on the terminal by checking "paste with right click" on the settings window under terminal tab.
Then you can use the right click as on putty.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a mouse with a wheel/3rd/middle button you can paste with that as well.

Comment: Do you know if that is a default behavior, or if it must be configured? Mice with scroll wheels often program the default middle/scroll-click behavior via drivers (which would supersede the MobaXTerm settings) to enable an all-direction pan control. Do you know if this would prevent the paste-by-middle-click? Your answer may be correct and even helpful, but if you could add more clarifying information it would be an even better answer.

Comment: Yes, it is default afaik. Every install I or my team have done, this has been default

Answer (score 0):

default paste shortcut now is: `shift-ctrl-insert`

Answer (score 0):

Use and joy ..

- `Ctrl+Insert` is works as the copy shortcut for selected text
- `shift+insert` is works as the paste shortcut

Answer (score -1):

My HP ELITE BOOK 840 G6 has no <kbd>insert</kbd> key. [It is not a joke...](https://laptopmedia.com/review/hp-elitebook-840-g6-review-one-for-the-classy-business-people-out-there/)
In the "Comments" section of the article, I found:

> There are some hidden functions:
>
> FN+R = Break
> FN+S = Sys Rq
> FN+C = Scroll Lock
> FN+E = Insert
> FN+W = Pause